# Hindi text does not show using Beamer

Tags: beamer, xetex, unicode

I am trying to write an example of using unicode font in Latex Beamer. The resulting pdf does not show the Hindi characters, rather shows blank spaces in that place. However, when I use the same code in documentclass[article], it is producing correct results. Can anyone please help where the problem lies?

```
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw} 


\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{framed,color}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{rgb}{0.93,0.91,0.91}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode} %Unicode extras!
\usepackage{xltxtra}  %Fixes

%\setmainfont{Bitstream Charter}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}
\newfontfamily\hindifont[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Writing unicode text: use of \textit{.ttf} files}

\begin{shaded}
\begin{verbatim}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{Lohit Hindi}
\texthindi{देवनागरी में लिखना बहुत आसान है |}

\end{document}
\end{verbatim}
\end{shaded}

This produces


\texthindi{देवनागरी में लिखना बहुत आसान है |}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Beamer uses sans serif font by default. This means you have to define `\hindifontsf` instead of the `\hindifont` which worked for article class.

Alternatively you could instruct beamer to use serif fonts by using `\usefonttheme{serif}`.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw} 

%\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hindi}
\newfontfamily\hindifontsf[Script=Devanagari]{Lohit Hindi}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\texthindi{देवनागरी में लिखना बहुत आसान है |}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]